# Как установить пароль на директорию в Debian?

Tags: debian, unix

Собственно, сабж. Имеется VPS с Debian 8.1, нужно поставить пароль на директорию, чтобы при попытке её изменить/в неё войти из консоли/ftp-менеджера - этот самый пароль запрашивался.

Comment: Вы можете создать пользователя и дать доступ к директории только для него.

Comment: Какого такого ftp-менеджера? FTP-клиента что ли?

Answer (score 1):

Доступ из консоли через chown chmod 
Доступ по ftp .ftpaccess

Comment: Старайтесь писать более развёрнутые ответы. Напишите, как нужно использовать эти инструменты, приведите примеры.

Answer (score 1):

Вам кажется, что вам нужен шелл, который после получения errno, равного EACCES 13 "permission denied" запрашивал бы владельца директории и предлагал ему авторизоваться. Этого нет и вам на самом деле это не нужно, ибо это вне специфики вашего бизнеса.